# Leaderboard email sent under incorrect circumstances

Tags: bug, email, reputation-leagues, beta-sites

This morning, as I checked my email, I noticed the following friendly email in my inbox:

> Hello,
>
> I just wanted to drop you a note to thank you for participating in the ongoing beta of Freelancing Stack Exchange, and to congratulate you for making the leaderboard!

The email continued from there, but when I clicked on the link for the leaderboard, I saw that I was not on the leaderboard, and was still at 191 reputation. However, I received the email around the time that I had been awarded the Quorum badge (post with 2 upvotes on Meta).

Basically, I think the system counted the meta score (191 + (2 * 5) = 201, enough for the leader board) to determine when to send the beta leaderboard email, when it shouldn't have.

Comment: Maybe be "leaderboard" they means all 36 users in the [first page of users, sorted by overall reputation](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/users?page=1&tab=reputation&filter=all). :)

Comment: Could it instead be an upvote that was taken back?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Haha, it's possible! However, I would have been on that list a little bit ago! This is [the link](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/alltime/freelancing.stackexchange.com) from the email.

Comment: I see, so it's indeed the leagues and you are probably correct. +1. :)

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby - It's possible, but I'm not sure it's probable; it's been relatively quiet. For example, the last two questions asked have been (as of right this second) 6 hours old and 45 minutes old.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, and I can confirm that it’s *not* related to Meta participation.

I got such an email for "participating in the ongoing beta of Mythology Stack Exchange", and it also says:

> […] and to congratulate you for making the [leaderboard](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/alltime/mythology.stackexchange.com)!

But I’m not on that leaderboard. See [my profile on Mythology SE](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/users/165/unor):

> [image]

- I have posted no answers and no questions (neither on Meta nor on the main site).
- I have only 103 reputation (thanks to +2 for an edit).